# whats wrong with juju!

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I have been working on Juju for very long and haven't touch the config file or set any permissions on the file. I don't know why Juju is doing mad here. First it doesn't show the last charms and its connections on the canvas. when I see on the Juju GUI it shows machine 1 and when I add some charms it come back to old stat and start showing 2 machine. Now I thought it should be the issue of GUI so I went to cli and now here I am seeing permissions error which I didn't face earlier.

```
$ juju add-relation glance cinder

You do not have permission to add a relation.
You may ask an administrator to grant you access with "juju grant".

ERROR permission denied (unauthorized access)
```

I can assure you guys I didn't change anything in configs or play with charms.
but Juju is throwing all this from no where.
any help will be highly appreciated.

Moreover I tried deploying Juju charm with "`juju deploy mysql`" it throws this error `ERROR open /home/ykhan/.local/share/juju/controllers.yaml: permission denied. controllers.yaml` file set to ROOT user. even i change the permission to the user ykhan. Again after few seconds said file because under user root.

Comment: ERROR open /home/ykhan/.local/share/juju/controllers.yaml: permission denied

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by changing permission of specified folder: `chown ykhan:ykhan -R /home/ykhan/.local/share/juju`

If this doesn't work then, try to make a new user and run your juju command with this new user.